# Having problems using a template container's constructor c++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm tryin to use a custom container, and in that container's constructor i pass a memory pool allocator.
The whole thing starts like this:

```
AllocatorFactory alloc_fac;

//Creates a CPool allocator instance with the size of the Object class
IAllocator* object_alloc = alloc_fac.GetAllocator<CPool>(1000,sizeof(Object));
//Creates a CPool allocator instance with the size of the BList<Object> class
IAllocator* list_alloc = alloc_fac.GetAllocator<CPool>(10,sizeof(BList<Object>));
//Same logic in here as well
IAllocator* node_alloc = alloc_fac.GetAllocator<CPool>(1000,sizeof(BListNode<Object>));
```

The IAllocator class looks like this:

```
 class IAllocator
{

public:

    virtual void* allocate( size_t bytes ) = 0;
    virtual void deallocate( void* ptr ) = 0;

    template <typename T>
    T* make_new()
    { return new ( allocate( sizeof(T) ) ) T (); }

    template <typename T, typename Arg0>
    T* make_new( Arg0& arg0 )
    { return new ( allocate( sizeof(T) ) ) T ( arg0 ); }

            .......
}
```

And the container class's constructor looks like this:

```
template <class T>
class BList {
......
public:
/**
 *@brief Constructor
 */
BList(Allocators::IAllocator& alloc){
     _alloc = alloc;
    reset();
    }
/**
 *@brief Constructor
 *@param inOther the original list
 */
 BList(const BList<T>& inOther){
    reset();
    append(inOther);
    }
.....
}
```

And when I do this:

```
 BList<Object> *list = list_alloc->make_new<BList<Object>>(node_alloc);
```

The compiler complains about this:

> Error  1   error C2664: 'Containers::BList::BList(Allocators::IAllocator &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Allocators::IAllocator *' to 'Allocators::IAllocator &' c:\licenta\licenta-transfer_ro-02may-430722\licenta\framework\framework\iallocator.h    21  Framework

I think i went over my head with this one....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existing answers are correct, but a quick note on how to read the error yourself: you just have to split it into pieces ...

```
Error 1 error C2664: 'Containers::BList::BList(Allocators::IAllocator &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Allocators::IAllocator *' to 'Allocators::IAllocator &'
```

reads:

- you're calling `Containers::BList::BList(Allocators::IAllocator &)`, which is a constructor taking one argument, a reference to an `IAllocator`
- `cannot convert parameter 1` means the compiler is having trouble with the type of that first (and only) argument

  - you've given it this type: `... from 'Allocators::IAllocator *'`
  - and it wanted this type (to match the constructor declaration): `... to 'Allocators::IAllocator &'`

so, how do you convert from the pointer you have to the reference the constructor wants?

---

OK, I've added the actual answer as well:

```
Allocators::IAllocator *node_alloc = // ...
Allocators::IAllocator &node_alloc_ref = *node_alloc;
BList<Object> *list = list_alloc->make_new<BList<Object>>(node_alloc_ref);
```

or just:

```
BList<Object> *list = list_alloc->make_new<BList<Object>>(*node_alloc);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. They're all valid, but since I can only mark one as a solution, I chose this because of its higher educational value :p .

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be calling `make_new` with a pointer instead of a reference. Try:

```
BList<Object> *list = list_alloc->make_new<BList<Object>>(*node_alloc);
```

And please, pick an indentation stile and stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your allocator factory is returning a pointer to an allocator, but your constructor wants a reference to an allocator. You need to dereference the pointer.

```
IAllocator* node_alloc = alloc_fac.GetAllocator<CPool>(1000,sizeof(BListNode<Object>));    

// Instead of:
// BList<Object> mylist(node_alloc);
// you need:
//
BList<Object> mylist(*node_alloc);
```